# Authentification doesn't work when trying to delete artifact ("HttpResponseException: Forbidden")

Tags: groovy, artifactory

I'm trying to remove artifacts from an Artifactory repository using a Groovy script that runs in a Jenkins task. The script collects all artifacts in the given path of my repository that match a timestamp and then tries to delete these from the repository.

The interesting part of the script looks like:

```
def base.url = 'http://name:port'
def repo = 'my-repo'
def path = 'my-path'
def artifact = 'my-artifact'
def url.to.delete = base.url + '/artifactory/' + repo + '/' + path + '/' + artifact 
print "url.to.delete = " + url.to.delete

def server = new RESTClient(base.url)
server.auth.basic('user', 'password')   
def resp = server.delete(path: url.to.delete)
```

The delete statement causes this exception

```
groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseException: Forbidden
    at groovyx.net.http.RESTClient.defaultFailureHandler(RESTClient.java:240)
    at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.doRequest(HTTPBuilder.java:508)
    at groovyx.net.http.RESTClient.delete(RESTClient.java:196)
    at groovyx.net.http.RESTClient$delete.call(Unknown Source)
    at Artifactory$_deleteartifactsWithTimestamps_closure2.doCall(hudson4086512083232103441.groovy:87)
    at Artifactory.deleteartifactsWithTimestamps(hudson4086512083232103441.groovy:80)
    at Artifactory$deleteartifactsWithTimestamps.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at Artifactory.deleteSnapshots(hudson4086512083232103441.groovy:32)
    at Artifactory$deleteSnapshots.call(Unknown Source)
    at hudson4086512083232103441.run(hudson4086512083232103441.groovy:170)
```

The calculated url.to.delete seems to be correct - if I copy it from the log and paste it to the address field of my browser, the artifact will be downloaded without problems. Artifactory can be reached from the Groovy script - a GET that collects the artifacts of the path works fine using the same data.

I use Artifactory 2.6.4 (the free version!), Groovy 2.1.1 with http-builder-0.6.jar.

Thanks for your help!

Frank

Comment: regarding Rick's reply, I loged into my Artifactory using the user and password used in the script and deleted an artifact in the UI without problems. So the user's permissions are good for deleting artifacts.

Comment: I just had a look at the log where I Found: "[DENIED DELETE] repo:path/my-artifact.war for anonymous/... ". So it seems that the problem is not the permission but the authentication. Is there something wrong with the authentification I used in my script: server.auth.basic('user', 'password')? Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that "Allow anonymous access" was switched on. After turning this off it is possible to use basic authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Your user probably doesn't have delete permissions. Your response suggests that the client call is correct.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm sure, that the user has admin permissions. I've used it to create and delete repositories. And I used username and password (copy & paste) to login into Artifactory.